# Content overlap with form angular7

Tags: angular

Have first time facing this strange bug, on mobile once click on any field and keyboard appear. It pushes all the content up and overlap with form.

Application is coded in Angular 7 and this bug is only on mobile version.

[image]

this is main component file and `app-layout` is main form and `app-slider` is just simple images carousel.

**Main Component**

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class=" wrapper h-100">
    <div class="row main pt-3 pb-3 pr-3 pl-3 clearfix">
      <div class="col-sm col-md-3">
        <app-layout></app-layout>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm col-md c4 d-none d-sm-block">
        <app-slider></app-slider>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- about us -->
    <div class="row mb-4" id="destination" #destinationRef>
      <div class="col col-4 d-none d-sm-block">
        <div class="g-block"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-text p-5 d-flex about-text">
        <h3>About us</h3>
        <p>
          Sabset.com is a platform of a community where proficient and trustful
          resources are available.
        </p>
        <h4>OUR MISSION:</h4>
        <p>
          is to provide consumer the very best and highly capable technicians to
          resolve the basic home and office requirements with in a very
          affordable rates.
        </p>
        <h4>OUR VISION:</h4>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- how it works section -->
    <div class="row" id="howitwork" #howitworkRef>
      <div class="col col-4 d-none d-sm-block">
        <div class="g-block"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-text p-5 d-flex">
        <h3>How its works</h3>
        <p>
          (" Consumer visit our website or application")
        </p>
        <p>
          (" Consumer fill the task on our website or application ")
          Congratulation you have done we will contact you shortly.
        </p>
        <div class="mt-3 mb-3">
          <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #contactForm="ngForm">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                name="name"
                id="name"
                [(ngModel)]="model.name"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Name"
                required
                #name="ngModel"
              />
              <div
                *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)"
                class="error"
              >
                <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
                  Name is required.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                name="email"
                id="email"
                [(ngModel)]="model.email"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="E-Mail"
                required
                email
                #email="ngModel"
              />
              <div
                *ngIf="email.invalid && (email.dirty || email.touched)"
                class="error"
              >
                <div *ngIf="email.errors.required">Email is required.</div>
                <div *ngIf="email.errors.email">
                  Email must be a valid email address.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea
                name="message"
                id="message"
                [(ngModel)]="model.message"
                rows="5"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Message"
                required
                #message="ngModel"
              ></textarea>
              <div
                *ngIf="message.invalid && (message.dirty || message.touched)"
                class="error"
              >
                <div *ngIf="message.errors.required">Message is required.</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="service-error" *ngIf="error">
              <h1>{{ error.errorTitle }}</h1>
              <h3>{{ error.errorDesc }}</h3>
            </div>
            <button
              [disabled]="!contactForm.form.valid"
              class="btn btn-primary float-right"
              type="submit"
            >
              Send Message
            </button>
          </form>
          <div [hidden]="!submitted" class="contact-message">
            <div *ngIf="model.id" class="contact-success">
              <h2 class="success">Success!</h2>
              <h4>Contact form has been successfully submitted.</h4>
              <br />
              <button (click)="gotoHome()" class="btn btn-info">
                Go to Home
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col d-flex mt-3">
            <ul class="list-inline w-100 h-social">
              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <img
                  src="../assets/gstore.png"
                  alt="Google Play"
                  class="img-fluid"
                />
              </li>
              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <img
                  src="../assets/astore.png"
                  alt="Apple Store"
                  class="img-fluid"
                />
              </li>
              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <img
                  src="../assets/facebook.png"
                  alt="Facebook"
                  class="img-fluid"
                />
              </li>
              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <img
                  src="../assets/instagram.png"
                  alt="Instagram"
                  class="img-fluid"
                />
              </li>
              <li class="list-inline-item">
                / official
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- footer -->
    <div class="footer d-flex flex-column">
      Ⓒ 2019. All Right Reserved.
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Layout Component**

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center h-100 customerForm">
    <!-- logo -->
    <div class="justify-content-center d-flex">
      <div [ngx-scroll-to]="'#destination'" class="tbtn">About us</div>
      <div [ngx-scroll-to]="'#howitwork'" class="tbtn">How It Works</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex  align-items-start pt-3 pr-3 pl-3">
      <img src="assets/logo2.png" class="img-fluid p-3" alt="Responsive image" />
    </div>

    <!-- request form -->
    <div class="w-100 pl-3 pr-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <form [formGroup]="customerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"
        class="pr-3 pl-3">
          <div class="example-container">
            <mat-form-field class="w-100">
              <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="name" />
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field class="w-100">
              <input
                matInput
                min="0"
                max="12"
                formControlName="phone"
                placeholder="Phone (only 11 digits)"
                value="03"
                (keypress)="numberOnly($event)"
              />
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field class="w-100">
              <input matInput placeholder="Email" formControlName="email" />
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field class="w-100">
              <mat-select placeholder="Location" formControlName="locations">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let loc of locations" [value]="loc.location">
                  {{ loc.location }}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>

            <!-- <mat-form-field class="w-100">
                  <mat-select placeholder="Service" formControlName="service">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let offer of service" [value]="offer.service">{{
                      offer.service
                    }}</mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field> -->
          </div>
          <mat-checkbox class="terms" formControlName="terms">
            <div (click)="openBottomSheet()">
              Accept our Terms & Conditions
            </div>
          </mat-checkbox>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
            <button class="btn pl-4 pr-4" [disabled]="!customerForm.valid">
              You Need Help!
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- request form end -->
  </div>
```

**SCSS**

```
html,
body {
  min-height:100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.wrapper{
  // background: url('../src/assets/webbg.png') bottom center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;

}
.bg{
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.tbtn{
  background: #283593;
  padding:20px 13px 5px;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0 0 0.4em 0.4em;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}


.btn{
  color: #fff;
  border: 0!important;
  border-radius: 40px;
  transition: all .3s ease 0s;
  background: #082146!important;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.terms{
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.termsText p:last-child{
  display: none!important;
}

.txtDelp p:last-child{
  display: none!important;
}

.main{
  // height: calc(100vh);
  height: 100%;
}

.g-block{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.about-text{
  background: url(../src/assets/bgsign.png) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
.col-text{

  flex-direction: column;
  color:#0c1f44;
  h3,h4{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: inherit;
  }

  p{
    font-size: 0.9em;
  }
}

.h-social .list-inline-item{
  color: #082146;
  font-weight: 700;

}

.footer{
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

Comment: You should provide code including css / html and any component libs you’re using

Comment: It appears to be something in your css keeping the bottom row anchored to the bottom of the screen

Comment: using some basic css for style, even update my css, check question

Comment: It seems that you're using a responsive layout in a css framework (bootstrap?)... It also seems that it's using flex-layout to achieve responsiveness. If so... does your layout switch from row to column in mobile devices? I've already seen problems similar like this in some browsers when using flex column layout. In this case, using a 'flex-shrink: 0' to your container flex when in small devices may help.

Comment: Taking a closer look at your code, I'd suggest you adding `flex-shrink: 0` to `col-text` CSS class.